# MERGE - When not matched INSERT's exception

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, ora-00001

i have a PL/SQL procedure using MERGE :

```
MERGE INTO 
  table_dest d
USING
  (SELECT * FROM my_Table) s
ON
  (s.id = d.id)
when matched     then UPDATE set d.col1 = s.col1
when not matched then INSERT (id, col1) values (s.id, s.col1);
```

now lets say the query `s` returns mutiple rows with same id wich will returns an **ORA-00001: unique constrain error**

what i want to do is to send the duplicated columns to another table **my_Table_recyledbin** to get a successful INSERT, can i use `EXCEPTION WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX` ? if yes how to use it with the MERGE statement?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not handle the archiving of duplicate rows to the recycle bin table in a separate statement?

Firstly, do your merge (aggregating the duplicate rows to avoid the unique constraint error). I've assumed a `MAX` aggregate function on col1, but you can use whatever suits your needs -- you have not specified how to decide which row to use when there are duplicates.

```
MERGE INTO 
  table_dest d
USING
  (SELECT a.id, MAX(a.col1) as col1
     FROM my_Table a
    GROUP BY a.id) s
ON
  (s.id = d.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET d.col1 = s.col1
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (id, col1) VALUES (s.id, s.col1);
```

Then, deal with the duplicate rows. I'm assuming that your recycle bin table does allow duplicate ids to be inserted:

```
INSERT INTO my_Table_recyledbin r (id, col1)
SELECT s.id, s.col1
  FROM my_Table s
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM my_Table t
                WHERE t.id = s.id
                  AND t.ROWID != s.ROWID)
```

Hopefully, that should fulfil your needs.

Comment: Thank you Tom this is really helpful, i will try it right now!

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just use an error-logging clause?  I.E., add this line at the end of your MERGE statement:

```
LOG ERRORS INTO my_Table_recycledbin
```

Comment: Thank you dave, i didnt know about the LOG ERRORS , i was reading about it and unfortunately it is saying that :
  

> The DML error logging functionality is not invoked when:    
- UPDATE or **MERGE** operations raise a **unique constraint or index violation**.